# Codebuild fails in the middle of the Dockerfile

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, containers, aws-codebuild

```
  43 |     # Install PHP Redis
  44 | >>> RUN apt-get install -y autoconf wget build-essential && \
  45 | >>>     wget https://pecl.php.net/get/redis-5.3.7.tgz && \
  46 | >>>     tar xzf redis-5.3.7.tgz && \
  47 | >>>     cd redis-5.3.7 && \
  48 | >>>     phpize && \
  49 | >>>     ./configure && \
  50 | >>>     make && \
  51 | >>>     make install && \
  52 | >>>     echo "extension=redis.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development && \
  53 | >>>     echo "extension=redis.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production && \
  54 | >>>     apt-get purge --autoremove -y autoconf wget build-essential && \
  55 | >>>     cd .. && \
  56 | >>>     rm redis-5.3.7.tgz && \
  57 | >>>     rm -rf redis-5.3.7
  58 |
```

---

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y autoconf wget build-essential --ignore-engines &&     wget https://pecl.php.net/get/redis-5.3.7.tgz &&     tar xzf redis-5.3.7.tgz &&     cd redis-5.3.7 &&     phpize &&     ./configure &&     make &&     make install &&     echo \"extension=redis.so\" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development &&     echo \"extension=redis.so\" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production &&     apt-get purge --autoremove -y autoconf wget build-essential &&     cd .. &&     rm redis-5.3.7.tgz &&     rm -rf redis-5.3.7" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

pls give me a solution to fix this build

this issue comes in the Codebuild while building an image with Dockerfile
am not sure why this error occurs, in codebuild while building in local everything works fine pls if anyone have suggestions pls let me know and thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try including `tar` as part of the packages you're installing with `apt-get`? Or does your image already have `tar` installed?